# Can I operate a relay and Bridge on same computer?

Tags: bridge

After ironing out several buggy problems with my Tor relay it's now been in operation for almost sixty days without problems (almost). Have one irritant left but it's not of to much concern.

System - Ubuntu 16.4 LTS

Question - Is it possible to run a bridge on the same computer with the relay?

Guesses - 1. a second version of tor would have to be in operation?
          2. Is it possible to share ports OR do I have to open two new ports along with the ports currently in operation?

Question - is there a link for Nyx that works with Ubuntu? Can't seem to find one.

Thanks for any help! Adri

Comment: Please make two posts for two unrelated questions. If you post a separate Nyx question, please link to it here in the comments or remove it from this post.

Answer (score 2):

You could run a relay and bridge on the same computer if you set up 2 instances of `tor`, but this should not be done. From the [FAQ](https://www.torproject.org/docs/faq.html.en#RelayOrBridge):

> ... ISPs or governments trying to block access to the Tor network can't
>   simply block all bridges.
>
> Being a normal relay vs being a bridge relay is almost the same
>   configuration: it's just a matter of whether your relay is listed
>   publicly or not.

If someone's Internet connection is censored, and they cannot connect to normal Tor relays, they would not be able to connect to your bridge either, because it would have the same IP as the relay you are already running.

Comment: While I'd mostly agree, it's not entirely clear that blocking happens on an IP-wide basis, it may be an IP:Port tuple basis. Though generally I agree, you'd want distinct IPs for them ideally.